# How to resolve getting video data from Django api to reactjs

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

Hello so I am working on a ReactJS and Django project, I have the Django API all set and ready with all the data now I just have to get the data from React and one of the data that I want to grab is a video.

So I tried to use JSON.parse() so I do not know if I am handling all this wrong but I am getting an error that says:

**`JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`**

**Code Below: Where I am trying to grab directly the video**

```
import React from 'react';
import './stylesheet/videoList.css';



const VideoList = (props) =>{

    let videos = props.listVideos
    return(

        <div>
            {videos.map(content =>{
                return(

                    <div key={content.id}>
                        <h3>{content.lecturer}</h3>
                   
                    
                        <video src={JSON.parse(content.video)} className='lecture__video'/>

                    </div>

                )
            })}

        </div>
    )
}

export default VideoList
```

**All of the objects coming from the Api looks like this**

0: {…}
​​
date: "2020-08-14"
​​
id: 8
​​
lecturer: "Prof Wha Suck Lee"
​​
module: "Mat105"
​​
video: "/media/lectures/mat105-Part2.mp4"

Comment: can you provide the json response you get from the API

Comment: What does the `content` object look like, specifically the video attribute?

Comment: date: "2020-08-14"
​​
id: 8
​​
lecturer: "Prof Wha Suck Lee"
​​
module: "Mat105"
​​
video: "/media/lectures/mat105-Part2.mp4"

Comment: Above is an example of one object that is how it is

Comment: Why are you trying to parse `content.video`? it's just a string. just use `content.video` without the `JSON.parse`

Comment: When I do that it does not show any video it is just blank

Comment: You probably need to add the host domain to `/media/lectures/mat105-Part2.mp4` since it's not included. It doesn't mean you need to parse it if the video is blank. you can simply inspect the element and make sure the data is there.

Comment: **"You probably need to add the host domain to /media/lectures/mat105-Part2.mp4"**  How do I do this please do not mind this silly question I am new to this whole thing so I am less knowledgable

Comment: When I run the code without the JSON.parse() this is the error that I getting when I check console...

**```HTTP “Content-Type” of “text/html” is not supported. Load of media resource http://localhost:3000/media/lectures/Contradiction_and_contraposition.mp4 failed.```**

Comment: You can do it in the frontend: `src={"http://your-domain.com" + content.video}` or you can do the same in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

first make sure that backend video api-data is coming with your server host. if you're using localhost then it should be like `http://localhost:8000/media/lectures/mat105-Part2.mp4`

```
const VideoList = (props) =>{

    let videos = props.listVideos
    return(

        <div>
            {videos.map(content =>{
                return(

                    <div key={content.id}>
                        <h3>{content.lecturer}</h3>
                   
                    
                        <video src={content.video} className='lecture__video'/>

                    </div>

                )
            })}

        </div>
    )
}

export default VideoList
```